# Hawking Radiation of normal gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation, unruh-effect

If the event horizon of a black hole can radiate, then is it possible that normal gravitational field also radiates? The radiation will probably be very low, but still there could be some.
Also by Unruh effect an accelerating body will experience more temperature ,then does objects at rest at different region of gravitational field experiences different temperature (equivalence principle) .

Comment: Yes in theory, but none of this has been observed.